# Is having the SECRET KEY in an environment variable better than having it in an untracked settings file?

Tags: django, django-settings, secret-key, dev-to-production

In a scenario where the project's settings.py file is split into base, development, and production, and only the base file is tracked in VCS. Is it a problem if the SECRET_KEY is hard-coded in the production settings file. Or will having it in an environment variable a better choice? If so, why?

Is having it pulled from the system somehow more secure than written in plain text inside the file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would say the security for both methods are the same. Written down in a file (which is not committed to the source code repository) or as a environment variable would have the same effect.

If your system is compromised in a way someone got access the server, both methods would expose your security key. So, it wouldn't make much difference.

Now, I would say using environment variable is a better strategy. Not related to security though. But usually it is not a good idea to rely on uncommitted files to run a project. It's one of the causes of the famous *in my machine it works* problems. And it also make initial setup of a project difficult for newcomers.

For this kind of settings and configuration management, there is a great python library called [Python Decouple](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/python-decouple). It's worth checking it out. I use it in every Django project I work with.

Comment: I agree that it's not a good idea to rely on uncommitted files to run a project, which is why I made README file that should guide me to properly define all missing settings variables. But Python Decouple seems like such a good idea that I might switch to it instead of split settings files.

Comment: Thanks! :-) +1 for the README. Also, complementing about settings: it's okay to have multiple settings files (dev, prod, ci, tests, etc.), as far as they all are committed to the repo. You can combine multiple settings + env vars (for the passwords, keys etc.). Of course that if you can maintain your project with a single settings module, this would be the best scenario. And python-decouple helps a lot in such scenarios. I always try to keep my projects with 1 settings, but sometimes you have to split it